# Как связать бота ВК с ботом Телеграм

Tags: telegram, vkontakte-api, бот

Всем привет. Такая нестандартная задача - есть бот ВК, пользователь отправляет ему сообщение, а этот бот отправляет уже сообщение телеграм боту, получает от него ответ и возвращает пользователю. Возможно ли такое реализовать?

Comment: Возможно. Что-то еще?

Comment: А как? Дайте пожалуйста хотя бы ссылку на такой "рецепт" если знаете, а то не получается найти хоть какой нибудь информации

Comment: На этом сайте рекомендуется добавлять к вопросу свои попытки решения. [edit]?

Comment: А чего тут нестандартного? Просто на сервере крутится event loop.... цикл крч. и всё.........чё тут искать........найди любого бота в гитхабе и посмотри как реализовано